# Using the Clohessy-Wiltshire equation, what would be the expression for ' r '?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, spacecraft, orbital-maneuver, astrodynamics

I'm looking for an expression for r. The difficulty I'm facing is simplifying the C-W equation

[image]

Comment: What's this from?

Comment: from an assignment of a course that I'm taking.

Comment: Best to show what you've done so far, so it's not just 'do my work for me'.

Comment: haha. I understand. I've arrived at the expression r= -0.519*(v/n) after simplification of the C-W matrix but I'm not sure about it